# Godot: audio stutter issue

Tags: audio, godot, gdscript

One of my playtesters reported an audio stutter issue that seems to happen when the player character is walking.

Video here for the normal game audio vs. my playtester's recording:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2ssc5hgn6caz2ao/AAAOurXJ_8Zh0Jm_RxMQn7VEa?dl=0

Game prototype is playable online here (on desktop browser) if you want to test it yourself:
https://mellowminx.itch.io/reincarnated-as-an-adorable-walking-rock-in-a-peaceful-gardening-sim-game?secret=DXXjBoYCoM6aKdqTM8rc1L6wjU

Any idea on how I can fix it? I haven't been able to replicate the issue on my own and it hasn't been reported by other playtesters. In my code for the footstep audio, the audio plays whenever the animation frame changes while the player character is walking:

```
func _ready():
    connect("frame_changed", self, "_on_frame_changed")
    
    
func footstep_grass_audio():
    var footstep_grass_audio_tracks = [
    $"%audio_footstep_grass_0",
    $"%audio_footstep_grass_1",
    $"%audio_footstep_grass_2",
    $"%audio_footstep_grass_3",
    $"%audio_footstep_grass_4",
    ]
    footstep_grass_audio_tracks.shuffle()
    var footstep_grass_audio_track = footstep_grass_audio_tracks[0]
    footstep_grass_audio_track.play()

func footstep_puddle_audio():
    var footstep_puddle_audio_tracks = [
    $"%audio_footstep_puddle_0",
    $"%audio_footstep_puddle_1",
    $"%audio_footstep_puddle_2",
    $"%audio_footstep_puddle_3",
    $"%audio_footstep_puddle_4",
    ]
    footstep_puddle_audio_tracks.shuffle()
    var footstep_puddle_audio_track = footstep_puddle_audio_tracks[0]
    footstep_puddle_audio_track.play()

func _on_frame_changed():
    if Global.current_movement != "bounce" && Global.terrain_type == "land":
        match frame:
            0, 1:
                footstep_grass_audio()
        match frame:
            1, 1:
                footstep_grass_audio()
    if Global.current_movement == "bounce" && Global.terrain_type == "land":
        match frame:
            1, 1:
                footstep_grass_audio()
    if Global.current_movement != "bounce" && Global.terrain_type == "water":
        match frame:
            0, 1:
                footstep_puddle_audio()
        match frame:
            1, 1:
                footstep_puddle_audio()
    if Global.current_movement == "bounce" && Global.terrain_type == "water":
        match frame:
            1, 1:
                footstep_puddle_audio()
```

Comment: I have experienced something that sounded similar on macOS. It randomly but only occurred when I was running a chrome based browser and a godot game. More specifically when I had both youtube and netflix open or shadertoy.com open. Closing the tab and reopening the game returned the audio to normal.

Comment: I think it also occurred when running a game while opening the iOS simulator. I don't know why it happened or how to debug it. This happened around v3.2 so I haven't noticed it in a while.